# Change css value depending on the selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Wondering if there is a way to change the left css value of this animation without having all the redundant code?

```
$('.recent .view-details-wrapp').css({opacity:0, left:33});
$('.recent .controls-wrapp').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.view-details-wrapp').stop()
        .animate({left:63}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
        .animate({opacity:'0.99'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
},function() {
    $(this).find('.view-details-wrapp').stop()
        .animate({left:33}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
        .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
});



$('.featured .view-details-wrapp').css({opacity:0, left:83});
$('.featured .controls-wrapp').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.view-details-wrapp').stop()
        .animate({left:103}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
        .animate({opacity:'0.99'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
},function() {
    $(this).find('.view-details-wrapp').stop()
        .animate({left:83}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
        .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `data` attribute and store the desired target values in these atrributes.

For example if you had markup like this:

```
<div data-target="0.1"></div>
<div data-target="0.2"></div>
...
<div data-target="0.8"></div>
<div data-target="0.9"></div>
```

you could use a single `hover`-binding to have all these divs fade to their according values:

```
$('div').hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast',$(this).data('target'));
},function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
});​
```

See **[a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JDQ55/1/)**

In your case that would probably mean that you attach the different values for `left` to your `.recent` and `.feature` elements and retrieve this data inside the hover handlers (the element triggering the hover can be usually referred to via `$(this)`)

Info on `data`-attributes can found at **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-%2a)**

Alternatively (in case you don't want to or cannot alter your markup) you can also find out what element has been triggering the hover inside the handler. So if you have:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

you can do:

```
$('div').hover(function(e){
    var t;
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('foo')){
       t = 0.2;
    } else if ($(e.target).hasClass('bar')){
       t = 0.8;
    }
    $(this).fadeTo('fast',t);
},function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
});​
```

where `e.target` is the target of the passed event. See **[another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGVSb/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help... the later should do the trick... Thanks Again!!

Comment: @Taylor doing it like this can get a little clumsy when you have lots of elements, but since you only have 2 it should be ok to handle it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Put the value in a variable.

```
var left = 83;

$('.recent .view-details-wrapp').css({opacity:0, left:left});
$('.recent .controls-wrapp').hover(function() {
$(this).find('.view-details-wrapp').stop()
    .animate({left:(left + 30)}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
    .animate({opacity:'0.99'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
},function() {
$(this).find('.view-details-wrapp').stop()
    .animate({left:left}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
    .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
});
```

Comment: That's not what he's asking I think. He wants to use the same lines for handling both hover on `$('.recent .view-details-wrapp')` and `$('.featured .view-details-wrapp')`

Comment: How would I apply the variable value to ".featured .view-details-wrapp"?

Comment: You could wrap this in a function where you insert the classes and the left as parameters.